Intersection of generalized eigenspaces is trivial (proof validation)
Does the following proof work for showing that the intersection of generalized eigenspaces is trivial?
Let $A$ be some $n \times n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\mu,\lambda$ where $\mu\neq \lambda$. The generalized eigenspaces are then $\ker(A-\mu I_n)^n$ and $\ker(A-\lambda I_n)^n.$ Assume that there is some non-vector $x \in \ker(A-\mu I_n)^n \cap \ker(A-\lambda I_n)^n$, then there is some $m\leq n$ such that $(A-\mu I_n)^mx=0$ and $(A-\mu I_n)^{m-1}x\neq0$.
Let $y :=(A-\mu I_n)^{m-1}x$. Then clearly $y$ is an eigenvector of $A$ to the eigenvalue $\mu$.
Now observe that $$(A-\lambda I_n)y=Ay-\lambda y = \mu y - \lambda y = (\mu-\lambda)y,$$ and by induction we have $(A-\lambda I_n)^ny=(\mu-\lambda)^ny.$ Since $\mu\neq \lambda$ and $y\neq 0$, we have $(A-\lambda I_n)^ny\neq 0$.
However, we also have $$(A-\lambda I_n)^ny = (A-\lambda I_n)^n(A-\mu I_n)^{m-1}x=(A-\mu I_n)^{m-1}(A-\lambda I_n)^nx=0,$$as $x\in \ker(A-\lambda I_n)^n$. Therefore $0\neq0$ is a contradiction and such $x$ cannot exist.
This proof is much shorter and elementary than other proofs I have found on the website, and therefore I have some doubts about it.

I think it works though the use of "clearly" is not something I'd recommend.  You can streamline it by assuming WLOG  that $\mu = 1$ and $\lambda =0$ and $\mathbf x \in \ker A \cap \ker (A-I)$ and expanding $\mathbf 0 = \big(A-I\big)^n\mathbf x $, then multiply each side by $A^k$ for well chosen $k$ to conclude $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$.  Writing $V = \ker A^n \oplus \text{image } A^n$ also yields a short proof.  There are many other approaches, e.g. this is forced to be true by Cayley Hamilton.

Yes, this works and is a nice approach. It does not need to phrased as a proof by contradiction: this argument shows directly that if $x \in \text{ker} \left( (A - \mu)^n \right)$ is nonzero then $x \not \in \ker \left( (A - \lambda)^m \right)$.
The argument can be generalized to work over any base field as follows.

Generalized linear independence of generalized eigenspaces: Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear endomorphism of a vector space $V$ over an arbitrary field $K$, and let $p(t), q(t) \in K[t]$ be two polynomials satisfying $\gcd(p, q) = 1$. Then $\ker(p(T)) \cap \ker(q(T)) = 0$.

Proof. By Bezout's lemma, there exist polynomials $a(t), b(t) \in K[t]$ such that $ap + bq = 1$, hence such that
$$a(T) p(T) + b(T) q(T) = 1.$$
Now if $v \in \ker(p(T))$ then applying both sides of this identity to $v$ gives $b(T) q(T) v = v$, hence $v \not \in \ker(q(T))$ unless $v = 0$. $\Box$
Note that again this does not need to be phrased as a proof by contradiction; we just show directly that the intersection is zero.
The argument can be motivated as follows: if $v \in \ker(p(T)) \cap \ker(q(T))$ then by definition $p(T) v = q(T) v = 0$. What we can conclude from this by repeatedly applying $T$ and taking linear combinations is exactly that $(a(T) p(T) + b(T) q(T)) v = 0$ for any other polynomials $a, b$. Now we ask ourselves how to choose $a, b$ such that this result is as informative as possible, and Bezout's lemma says we can choose $a, b$ such that $ap + bq = \gcd(p, q)$. There is an exactly analogous argument for abelian groups which shows that if an element $a \in A$ of an abelian group is $n$-torsion (meaning $na = 0$) and $m$-torsion (meaning $ma = 0$) then it is $\gcd(n, m)$-torsion.
